# Laravel - display name instead of id

Tags: php, html, laravel, eloquent, relationship

Need help, how do I display the name of the driver instead of the id? I have more tables but if only someone can help me with one i'll be more that glad, the table show me the number of the ID 1, 2, 3... i have tried to change the model, Im learning php and lavarel an still this part do not get clear for me. Thx for the help

register model;

```html
class register extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    use HasFactory;

    public $table = 'registers';
    
    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];

    public $fillable = [
        'driver_id',
        'inOut',
        'plates',
        'carrier_id',
        'tractorNumber',
        'process_id',
        'location_id',
        'customer',
        'drayage_id',
        'containertype_id',
        'containerstatus_id',
        'containerPlate',
        'containerNumber',
        'comments'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'driver_id' => 'integer',
        'inOut' => 'string',
        'plates' => 'string',
        'carrier_id' => 'integer',
        'tractorNumber' => 'string',
        'process_id' => 'integer',
        'location_id' => 'integer',
        'customer' => 'string',
        'drayage_id' => 'integer',
        'containertype_id' => 'integer',
        'containerstatus_id' => 'integer',
        'containerPlate' => 'string',
        'containerNumber' => 'string',
        'comments' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'driver_id' => 'required',
        'inOut' => 'required',
        'carrier_id' => 'required',
        'process_id' => 'required',
        'location_id' => 'required',
        'drayage_id' => 'required',
        'containertype_id' => 'required',
        'containerstatus_id' => 'required'
    ];

}
```

driver model

```html
class driver extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    use HasFactory;

    public $table = 'drivers';
    

    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];



    public $fillable = [
        'driverName',
        'licence'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'driverName' => 'string',
        'licence' => 'string'
    ];

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'driverName' => 'required',
        'licence' => 'required'
    ];
    
}
```

```html
  @foreach($registers as $register)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $register->driver_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $register->inOut }}</td>
            <td>{{ $register->plates }}</td>
            <td>{{ $register->carrier_id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $register->tractorNumber }}</td>
```

Comment: Did you set up a Relationship between `Register` and `Driver`? If you did, you can do `$register->driver->name`. If you didn't, then you either need to do that, or manually `join()` them, then display via `$register->driver_name`. You didn't show how you're defining `$registers`, so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67909059/edit) your question to include that. Also, Model names are `StudlyCase`, `Register` and `Driver`, not `register` and `driver`. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a relationship between driver and register models, you can write that relationship in the **register model class**.

```
public function driver()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(driver::class, 'driver_id');
}
```

Then you can get driver name by typing,

```
@foreach($registers as $register)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $register->driver->driverName}}</td>
                <td>{{ $register->inOut }}</td>
                <td>{{ $register->plates }}</td>
                <td>{{ $register->carrier_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $register->tractorNumber }}</td>
           </tr>
 @endforeach()
```

Comment: Sorry! It's just a mistake! But it is still working even we use drivers(plural) instead of driver(singular) also.

Comment: Yes, it's just a naming convention; the functionality is the same, but it's best to use proper pluralization for what the name represents. Code readability is important  When I review code and see pluralization that doesn't match variable/return type, I flag it for fix in the same way I would for code that doesn't work.

Comment: Thx!!! This solve my problem! I was adding the code in the driver model